# Missing xslt webpart viewer

Tags: xslt

I am looking to add an Xslt viewer to the homepage of my site but cannot find it in any of the available web part categories

Do I need to enable a specific site feature to make it available?

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint? Using the browser, in a web part page edit the page, then click "Add a Web Part", then select the list and click Add. That will add an XSLT list view of the selected list. in the browser. In a wiki page, edit the page, click Insert > Existing List, select the list and click "Add".

AFAIK there is no other way to add an XSLT list view web part using the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that there is  "XSLT List View Web Part" in SharePoint, No "Xslt viewer".

If you want to add XSLT List View Web Part on page then you have to add it from SharePoint designer. You can also change look and feel of it from SPD. Look,

[XSLT List View Web Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff630941%28v=office.14%29.aspx)